# creating a string split function in C++

Tags: c++, string, pass-by-reference, static-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Splitting a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c)

Im trying to create a function that mimics the behavior of the `getline()` function, with the option to use a delimiter to split the string into tokens.
The function accepts 2 strings (the second is being passed by reference) and a `char` type for the delimiter. It loops through each character of the first string, copying it to the second string and stops looping when it reaches the delimiter. It returns `true` if the first string have more characters after the delimiter and `false` otherwise. The position of the last character is being saved in a static variable.
for some reason the the program is going into an infinite loop and is not executing anything:

```
const int LINE_SIZE = 160;
bool strSplit(string sFirst, string & sLast, char cDelim) {
    static int iCount = 0;
    for(int i = iCount; i < LINE_SIZE; i++) {
        if(sFirst[i] != cDelim)
            sLast[i-iCount] = sFirst[i];
        else {
            iCount = i+1;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The function is used in the following way:

```
while(strSplit(sLine, sToken, '|')) {
    cout << sToken << endl;
}
```

Why is it going into an infinite loop, and why is it not working?
I should add that i'm interested in a solution without using `istringstream`, if that's possible.

Comment: As I read your post, I see no questions, only statements. Do you have a question for us?

Comment: @Rob probably the infinite loop was not desired outcome.

Comment: Not directly to your current problem. Do you want this function to work only a single sLine? The static variable is not reset for a second sLine.

Comment: @ÖöTiib - I agree. But that doesn't excuse the poster from asking a question. In my experience, posts without questions result in a confusing array of answers, each answering a different (unstated) question.

Comment: @Robᵩ I accepted your comment and edited my original post.

Comment: see this for a multitude of solutions to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/236129/1025391

Comment: @PermanentGuest - This function should work for multiple lines, and should reset the static variable for each line.

Comment: Again not the question you asked (that's been answered already) but the design of this function is terrible. It's the static variable that is the problem, it means that the function cannot be used in a nested fashion. That is you cannot have an outer loop and an inner loop both calling strSplit because both loops will be sharing the same static variable. Here's a better way to design this function. Have the function remove the split string and the delimiter from sFirst. That way strSplit can always start at the beginning of sFirst and you don't need the static variable.

Comment: Congrats for trying to write your own utility functions though. Clearly you have what it takes.

Comment: @john both, the OP's and your approach won't be thread-safe in the end.

Comment: @moooeeeep No-one's asking for thread safety.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not exactly what you asked for, but have you considered `std::istringstream` and `std::getline`?

```
// UNTESTED
std::istringstream iss(sLine);
while(std::getline(iss, sToken, '|')) {
  std::cout << sToken << "\n";
}
```

---

**EDIT**:

> Why is it going into an infinite loop, and why is it not working?

We can't know, you didn't provide enough information. Try to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and post that.

I *can* tell you that the following line is very suspicious:

```
       sLast[i-iCount] = sFirst[i];
```

This line will result in undefined behavior (including, perhaps, what you have seen) in any of the following conditions:

- `i >= sFirst.size()`
- `i-iCount >= sLast.size()`
- `i-iCount < 0`

It appears to me likely that all of those conditions are true.  If the passed-in string is, for example, shorter than 160 lines, or if `iCount` ever grows to be bigger than the offset of the first delimiter, then you'll get undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks, but im trying to achieve that without using `istringstream`, if thats possible.

Answer (score 3):

`LINE_SIZE` is probably larger than the number of characters in the `string` object, so the code runs off the end of the string's storage, and pretty much anything can happen.

Instead of rolling your own, `string::find` does what you need.

```
std::string::size_type pos = 0;
std::string::size_type new_pos = sFirst.find('|', pos);
```

The call to `find` finds the first occurrence of '|' that's at or after the position 'pos'. If it succeeds, it returns the index of the '|' that it found. If it fails, it returns `std::string::npos`. Use it in a loop, and after each match, copy the text from [pos, new_pos) into the target string, and update `pos` to `new_pos + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure it's the `strSplit()` function that doesn't return or is it your caller `while` loop that's infinite?

Shouldn't your caller loop be something like:

```
while(strSplit(sLine, sToken, '|')) {
    cout << sToken << endl;
    cin >> sLine >> endl;
}
```

-- edit --

if value of `sLine` is such that it makes `strSplit()` to return true then the `while` loop becomes infinite.. so do something to change the value of `sLine` for each iteration of the loop.. e.g. put in a `cin`..

Comment: You're right, it is the `while` loop thats giving me trouble, but i'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
std::vector<std::string> spliString(const std::string &str, 
                                    const std::string &separator)
{
    vector<string>      ret;
    string::size_type   strLen = str.length();
    char                *buff;
    char                *pch;

    buff = new char[strLen + 1];
    buff[strLen] = '\0';
    std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), buff);

    pch = strtok(buff, separator.c_str());
    while(pch != NULL)
    {
        ret.push_back(string(pch));
        pch = strtok(NULL, separator.c_str());
    }

    delete[] buff;

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: He wants to figure out what's wrong with "his" code..